# How to run PHP with crontab on ubuntu?

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I try to run PHP script auto per 1 minutes.

Here is my php code in file asterisk_auto.php

```
<?php
$date = "Today is " . date("Y/m/d h:m:s").PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("status.txt", $date, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

I try to setup a crontab.

My detail system info are:

[image]

And I setup my crontab is:

[image]

Final the crontab status is:

[image]

But it does not write anything to file status.txt. What is going wrong?

Comment: run "cd" to someware, or add path to "status.txt". the file you output to could be anywhere. maybe on / or /root

Comment: yes, thanks for your help.